# Who invented the gamma distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

Who was the first person who invented the gamma distribution? Can you also give the reference of the article in which he/she did that.

Comment: See [Name of the Gamma function](//hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6495).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the answer to my question. Thanks again.